# How to create stopwatch time in django

Tags: python, django, time, django-models

I want for create a field that can take input in the form:

mm:ss.xx

currently I am using the following code, but it only interprets hours:mins:secs

```
models.TimeField(default='7:00')
```

My applologies for the basic question but my googles and documentation searches have been to no avail

Answer (score 0):

time default formats in django or see [formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS) :

```
    '%H:%M:%S',     # '14:30:59'
    '%H:%M:%S.%f',  # '14:30:59.000200'
    '%H:%M',        # '14:30'
```

in your form

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('time_field', )
        widgets = {
            'time_field': forms.TimeInput(format='%M:%S.%f'),
        }
```